# systemd - python script not rotating log files when run as systemd service

Tags: python, systemd

I have a python3 web service written using cherrpy framework. This script works fine when run inside a screen session or just directly from shell. This script rotates logs daily using TimedRotatingFileHandler from python's logging module. This works fine.

I have written a simple systemd unit file to make this script run as a service. Code below:

```
[Unit]
Description=RCS API Server
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/rcs-sender/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/rcs-sender/rcs_api_server.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Once the script is run using this until file, it no longer rotates logs, and appends everything to current logging file. I've watched it roll through midnight and not change log files. What is systemd doing that would prevent the script from rotating log files, and how can this be prevented?

Comment: Are you sure your system time is correct?  When running the script local it may be using some local time and not using system UTC time.  Just a thought

Comment: How would it do this? It is only run inside an AWS instance that uses UTC system time. The behaviour only changes when I run it using systemd.